# How to monitor a delayed_job started using jruby-rack-worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, delayed-job, monitor

I have a jruby on rails based application deployed over tomcat using war file generated through warbler gem. I have started a worker using jruby-rack-worker for delayed_job.

All the jobs are getting processed properly but I have setup tool to monitor the worker. How can I get current status for the delayed_job ?

Answer (score 0):

This gem gives you stats to view regarding your delayed jobs. I use it and works great.
https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web

Comment: would be nice if it worked out but might just not, *jruby-rack-worker* hacks (introduces a new worker sub-class that is than started inside a thread within the same JVM process) DJ's assumptions to run per process and makes it thread-safe. thus do you actually have any feedback from using *delayed_job_web* with threaded-workers under JRuby ?

Comment: delayed_job_web is a nice tool to have look at the stats but it wont help to monitor the delayed_job worker.